# Angular doesn't see the injected service

Tags: angular, error-handling, components

I want to create kind of interceptor for error handler. That's why I create the files:

ErrorService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class ErrorService {
       name : any;

        constructor() {
        }

        setName(message:string){
            this.name = message;
        }

        getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        error(detail: string, summary?: string): void {
            this.name = detail;
        }
    }
```

AppErrorHandler:

```
import { ErrorService } from './error-service';
import { ErrorHandler, Inject  } from '@angular/core';


export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(@Inject(ErrorService) private errorService: ErrorService){

    }

    handleError(error : any){
        this.errorService.setName(error.status);
        console.log('getter', this.errorService.getName());
        console.log('test error ', error);        
    }    
}
```

To that point everything goes quite good. When I print an error in `handleError` it prints correctly.

But when I want to pass the `ErrorService` object into the `ErrorComponent` suddenly Angulas can't see it.

ErrorComponent:

```
import { ErrorService } from './../common/error-service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'error',
  templateUrl: './error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error.component.css']
})
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {
    console.log('from ErrorComponent, ', this.errorService);
  }

  message = this.errorService.getName();


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And ErrorComponent.html

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  Error!!! {{message}}
</div>
```

Of course I have added some imports in `app.module`:

```
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
...
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    PostService,
    ErrorService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: AppErrorHandler}

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**The problem is that in `AppErrorHandler` I am passing the error to the `ErrorService` and the I want to display it in `ErrorComponent` but `ErrorComponent` doesn't see the passed data**

**UPDATE:**
I followed the below solution and get one error. My `errorComponent` looks like:

```
import { ErrorService } from './../common/error-service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'error',
  templateUrl: './error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error.component.css']
})
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
  errorService: ErrorService;
  message: string;

  constructor(errorService: ErrorService) {
    this.errorService = errorService;
    console.log('------ from error component ', errorService.name, this.errorService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And the `html` file:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  Error!!! {{errorService.name}}
</div>
```

And the problem is that I can't actually print the name property in the browser. In chrome console I have:
[image]

so you can see that I can easliy get the whole object ErrorService but couldn't get the property name which in console is `undefined` - why? And because of that I can't display it properly.

Comment: where is the problem ?? what kind of error you get ?

Comment: Don't use `@Inject` when injecting `ErrorService` into `AppErrorHandler`. @Inject is for primitive values/types. Just do `constructor( private errorService: ErrorService){}`. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: The problem is that in `AppErrorHandler` I am passing the error to the `ErrorService` and the I want to display it in `ErrorComponent` but `ErrorComponent` doesn't see the passed data

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky when I delete it I got an error in browser: `compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppErrorHandler: (?).`

Comment: Your code seems to be working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ep2aHZlApeVVt8FNATd5?p=preview)

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky but it doesn't

Comment: See my updated answer. I think I understand what you are going for. A few simply changes and that should help overall. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to resolve your issue:

1) To be able to effectively inject `ErrorService` into `AppErrorHandler`, you will want to decorate `AppErrorHandler` with `Injectable()`. With that you can remove the `@Inject(ErrorService)` and simply inject the service in the standard fashion.

```
import { ErrorService } from './error-service';
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable  } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService){}   
}
```

2) In `AppErrorHandler` you are targeting a property `status` of the error object. Keep in mind that standard error objects have properties such as `message`, `name`, `description`, and `number` depending on the browser. You may want to check whether the `status` property exists before attempting to get it's value, otherwise you could get `undefined` for non HTTP errors.

**Update:** make sure to call `super(true);` and `super.handleError(error);` or `throw error;` to ensure errors are re-thrown and default error handling occurs after your custom error handling. Otherwise the errors will be swallowed by the custom error handler.

export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

```
// ...

handleError(error : any) {
    // rethrow exceptions
    super(true);

    if(error.status) {
        console.log(error.status);
        this.errorService.setName(error.status);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Message: ', error.message);  
        console.log('Description: ', error.description);
        this.errorService.setName(error.message);
    }

    console.log('Getter: ', this.errorService.getName());

    // trigger default error handling after custom error handling
    super.handleError(error);
}
```

}

3) In your error component, to actively see the changes to the `name` property of the `ErrorService`, at minimum you'd want to make the `name` property a public property. Then in the ErrorComponent, you'd target the injected service's `name` property to display. A more scalable approach would be using RxJS Subject for example to emit changes that the `ErrorComponent` can subscribe to. Doing `message = this.errorService.getName();` will not reset/react to changes to the name property automatically when errors occur. You'd need to either attach to the public property and/or use observables or similar to emit changes to components to subscribe to. See **Update 2** below for example of how to utilize RxJS Subject to update `message`.

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {
   public name : any;

   constructor() {}
```

**ErrorComponent HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <!-- Angular will detect changes to the services' -->
  Error!!! {{errorService.name}}
</div>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u05cMVdmGCBkPwhVraMv?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality. Click the button to trigger an error, in this case calling a method that does not exist.

**Update:** `console.log('------ from error component ', errorService.name, this.errorService);` in the constructor is logging `undefined` because at the time the `constructor()` runs, the public property `name` has no default value. If you want a default value, you can set that in `ErrorService` doing `public name: string = 'foobar';`. The [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u05cMVdmGCBkPwhVraMv?p=preview) has been updated to show the logging before and after `name` of `ErrorService` is being set. If you add a default value in `ErrorService` you'll see your log, prints the `name` property value.

**Update 2:** If you absolutely need to use `message` on `ErrorComponent` rather than any other property for displaying the value, including the `ErrorService`'s public `name` property, you can use Subject and Observable to subscribe to emitted changes to update the name property similar to [Parent/Child Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). This would involve instantating a new Subject on `ErrorService`, exposing public Observable property and subscribing to those changes. This shows how to use specifically `message` property of `ErrorComponent` getting values from `ErrorService` and it's `name` property. You may not really need the name property if the only goal is to display the error in `ErrorComponent`. Additionally in the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K1stzP3D7RwvByfFyFgU?p=preview), it is displaying the HTTP error status code in the `message` property of `ErrorComponent`.

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {
  public name: string;

  // create new Subject
  private nameSource = new Subject<any>();

  // expose Observable property
  error$ = this.nameSource.asObservable();

  setName(message: string){
    this.name = message;
    // emit error
    this.nameSource.next(this.name);
  }

  // ...
}

@Component({ // ... })
export class ErrorComponent {
  message: string = '';

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {
    // same stuff as before

    // subscribe to Observable from ErrorService and update name property on changes
    this.errorService.error$.subscribe(name => {
      this.message = name;
    });
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
    private errorService: ErrorService;

    constructor(errorService: ErrorService) {
      super(true);
      this.errorService = errorService;
      console.log(this.errorService);
    }

    handleError(error : any) {
        if(error.status) {
            console.log(error.status);
            this.errorService.setName(error.status);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Message: ', error.message);  
            console.log('Description: ', error.description);
            this.errorService.setName(error.message);
        }
    }    
}
```

Here is an updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K1stzP3D7RwvByfFyFgU?p=preview).

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Please have a look at my update. I have followed your instructions but I came across to one error which is crucial. Are you able to help me?

Comment: At the time the `constructor()` within `ErrorComponent` runs, there is no error assigned to the property `name` in `ErrorService` as it has no default value. That is why `name` is undefined when yo utry to log it. I've updated the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ep2aHZlApeVVt8FNATd5?p=preview) to show before and after logging `errorService.name`. If you want a default value for `name`, in `ErrorService` you can do something like `public name: string = 'foobar'`, otherwise it will be `undefined` at time of `constructor()`. `ErrorService` is effectively singleton when imported in main module.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. The reason why I mentiond my errorService name is not defined it not that I would like to assign some text to it like "foobar". The reason is that I would like to assign to variable errorService http error status - e.g. 500, 403, 404. And I have a example that I call on purpose error and I see it in console like my update looks like. But the think is I can't assign to the variable `message` (which is in `error component`) variable from `errorService.name`. What you showed me is to assiging random text to `errorService.name` which is not my goal.

Comment: Assignig value to the `errorService.name` is in the `error handler` and looks like: `handleError(error : any){
        this.errorService.name = error.status;` And the from the `errorService` I want to dispaly this variable `name` in the `error component`.

Comment: The code your want to use has NO mechanism to specifically update the `message` property when the `name` property of `ErrorService` has changed. Of course you don't want "foobar" as the `name` property's value, it was just demonstrating how to set it and display it as well as why it was logging `undefined`. My answer and plunker successfully showed how to display the value of an error when errors occur using the custom `ErrorHandler`, `ErrorService`, and `ErrorComponent by binding to the public `name` property of `ErrorService`.

Comment: If part of the issue is you do not understand how to extract the HTTP error status code out of the error supplied to `handleError()`, then you should submit a separate question. If you absolutely need `message` to be used in `ErrorComponent` rather than you will likely need to us RxJS objects such as Subject or Observable to emit changes that `ErrorComponent` can listen to and update message accordingly. That too would be a separate question.

Comment: I've updated the answer and the plunker to utilize the RxJS Subject as well as how to display the HTTP error status code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `forwardRef()`

```
import { Inject, Injectable, forwardRef } from "@angular/core";

export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => ErrorService)) private errorService: ErrorService){

    }

    ...
}
```